# Accessing a local file in custom iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm building my own custom SDK, but I keep running into the same issue... I'm not able to load my metallib file inside my SDK. It keeps saying that my file can't be found.

How I set it up

- Created a framework project
- Created a separate xcode swiftUI project. And linked the SDK using pods (see code down below)
- Created a metallib file, and used "copy bundle resources" to include it in my project (can see it in the navigator in the root)

My code for loading the metallib file

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
            
            if let path = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: "shaders", ofType: "metallib") {
                print(path)
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                print(url)
                let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            } else {
                print("Failed to find shaders.metallib in framework bundle")
            }
            
            if let libraryURL = frameworkBundle.url(forResource: "shaders", withExtension: "metallib") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: libraryURL)
                print("Successfully loaded metallib data: \(data)")
                
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    library = try metalDevice.makeLibrary(URL: libraryURL)
                } else {
                    fatalError("iOS min deployment target not met")
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to find shaders.metallib in framework bundle")
            }
```

My best guess is that is is not loading from the framework, but using my test application where I load my SDK

Can someone help me out?